# Trying to run a macro in Excel after updating data source using Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, automation

I have multiple reports that get updated on a regular basis and I'm trying to write a Python script that will pull data from the data report, paste it into the final report, and then run a macro in the final report.

I am able to copy the data over but the code I have isn't running the macro in the Excel sheet.

I've confirmed that the Module and macro name are correct but I'm not sure what the problem is in the code.

Looking for help on how to get the code to run the macro once the new data is copied into the workbook.

```
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl as xl
import xlwings as xw
import os, os.path
import win32com.client
import time

# opening the source excel file
filename ="C:\\Users\\...\\Copy Paste Test\\Source.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
  
# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="C:\\Users\\...\\Copy Paste Test\\Destination.xlsm"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
ws2 = wb2.active
  
# calculate total number of rows and 
# columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column
  
# copying the cell values from source 
# excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value

if os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\...\\Copy Paste Test\\Destination.xlsm"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb3 = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\...\\Copy Paste Test\\Destination.xlsm"), ReadOnly=1) #create a workbook object
    xl.Application.Run("Destination.xlsm!Module2.Macro1")
    wb3.Close(False) #close the work sheet object rather than quitting excel
    del wb3
    del xl
        
# saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the macro be run after `wb2` is saved, not before?

Comment: I tried that and put the macro block of code after it saves and it still doesn't run the macro.